# Comprehending List Comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have been recently introduced to list comprehensions, however, I am not certain I understand them completely.

So, I did a quick search through the docs and google. 
I found the docs section over data structures.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

While that gives me an idea with how they work, call me strange, I want to have a more mature understanding of how they operate.

Here is an example from the docs:

```
>>>[(x, y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x != y]
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4)]
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but this is how I understand how the list is evaluating.

- It looks like the list comprehension evaluates from left to right.
- This comprehension introduces X and Y.
- Then defines X and Y by the lists and evaluates based on position in list as well as the if condition.
- Due to X being assigned as the first variable, like the outside of a nested for loop, it is called first and iterated against Y's list.
- The if condition makes it so the comprehension only produces pairs that are not similar as X iterates through Y's list.

Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect. 
I welcome more complex examples for comprehensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing magic about nested list comprehensions. I think you're simply not seeing their simplicity yet!

This:

```
#      X           A                   B               C
a = [(x, y)   for x in [1,2,3]   for y in [3,1,4]   if x != y]
```

is simply syntactic sugar for:

```
__tmp = []
for x in [1,2,3]:                   # A
    for y in [3,1,4]:               # B
        if x != y:                  # C
            __tmp.append((x, y))    # X

a = __tmp
```

So you take the `for ... in ...` parts and re-assemble them as nested `for` loops. You then take the `if`s and nest it in the corresponding `for` loop; finally, you take the first part (`(x, y)` in this case) and you nest at the deepest part of the nested `for` structure.

This works out fine also when `if`s appear at multiple "stages" in a list comprehension, for example:

```
#      X         A                 B               C               D
a = [(x, y)   for x in [1,2,3]   if x >= 2   for y in [3,1,4]   if x != y]
```

translates (desugars) to:

```
__tmp = []
for x in [1,2,3]:                     # A
    if x >= 2:                        # B
        for y in [3,1,4]:             # C
            if x != y:                # D
                __tmp.append((x, y))  # X

a = __tmp
```

So again... it's just exactly the same as the comprehension with colons interspersed between the parts, and the inner part brought right in the front. The order of the `A B C D ...` part is always the same and never changed; it's only the `X` part that's moved from the back to the front.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I was making it out to be much more complex than it is. I really appreciate your thorough explanation.