# python appending elements to a list from a list

Tags: python, list, while-loop, append, extend

I would like to create a list that adds elements alternately from 2 seperate lists in python .
I had the following idea but it doesn't seem to work:

```
t1 = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
t2 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
t3= [len(t1)+len(t2)]
a = 0

while a < len(t1)+len(t2):
    t3.extend(t1[a])
    t3.extend(t2[a])
    a = a + 1
print t3
```

So basically I would like ['Jan',31,'Feb',28,'Mar',31, ect...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
t1 = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
t2 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
t3 = list()

for i, j in zip(t1, t2):
  t3.append(i)
  t3.append(j)

print(t3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest solution may be:

```
list(sum(zip(t2, t1), ()))
```

Comment: In general, [don't use `sum` to flatten a list, it is O(n^2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python/952952#952952).

Answer (score 2):

1. In Python you don't need to "reserve capacity" for a list. Just write

   ```
   t3 = []
   ```

   In fact, `t3 = [len(t1)+len(t2)]` doesn't even creates a list with length 24, but creates a list with a single entry [24].
2. `t1[a]` and `t2[a]` are elements you want to add to the list. To add an element, you use the `.append` method:

   ```
   t3.append(t1[a])
   t3.append(t2[a])
   ```

   `.extend` is used to add a list (in fact, any iterable) to a list, e.g.

   ```
   t3.extend([t1[a], t2[a]])
   ```
3. The problem itself can be solved easily using [list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282080/comprehending-list-comprehensions).

   ```
   [a for l in zip(t2, t1) for a in l]
   ```

There are many other improvements could be made (e.g. use a for loop instead of a while loop). You could take it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

---

(BTW, this code does not handle leap year.)

Answer (score 1):

Just `zip` the lists and flatten the result.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> t1 = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
>>> t2 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
... 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
>>> list(chain(*zip(t2, t1)))
['Jan', 31, 'Feb', 28, 'Mar', 31, 'Apr', 30, 'May', 31, 'Jun', 30, 'Jul', 31, 'Aug', 31, 'Sept', 30, 'Oct', 31, 'Nov', 30, 'Dec', 31]
```

Without `chain`:

```
>>> [x for tup in zip(t2, t1) for x in tup]
['Jan', 31, 'Feb', 28, 'Mar', 31, 'Apr', 30, 'May', 31, 'Jun', 30, 'Jul', 31, 'Aug', 31, 'Sept', 30, 'Oct', 31, 'Nov', 30, 'Dec', 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably have to read more about python lists and their methods. `t3= [len(t1)+len(t2)]` this is not necessary at all. I guess you have a C background and trying to initialize the list with size. In python you don't have to initialize the list size (its auto increasing). And the items you have in a list are not stored as per the **sequence** you have entered them in. Please check `tuple` in python if you want your items to be in the same sequence.
Happy Coding

Comment: yes I started learning python today. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
t2 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

arr = []

for i in range(12):
    arr.append(t2[i])
    arr.append(t1[i])

print(arr)
```

Output -

```
['Jan', 31, 'Feb', 28, 'Mar', 31, 'Apr', 30, 'May', 31, 'Jun', 30, 'Jul', 31, 'Aug', 31, 'Sept', 30, 'Oct', 31, 'Nov', 30, 'Dec', 31]
```

You can alternatively write -

```
import itertools

arr = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(t2, t1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can't create lists with a fixed length like you can do with arrays in other languages, so the third line should just be `t3 = []`.

Also, the `extend()` function is used to concatenate lists. To add a single new value, you need to use the `append()` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Python is dynamic programming language, the type of the identifier is determined when it is assigned value.
so basically you can do in this way:

```
t1 = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
t2 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
t3= []
for a in range(len(t1)):
    append.append(t1[a])
    apppend.append(t2[a])
print t3
```